# Create an animated search button

Tags: animation, search, button, icons

How can i create an animated search button with google material icons by using html ,css and jquery and then search all content with this button?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Nobody knows how can i do it?

Comment: Just i want to search all content in a page with jquery.how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `<button>` and then use some class form animate.css

> plugin (link->  https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Comment: Thanks.but i need a jquery code for search all content with this button.